Проблема @media в CSS размер шрфита применяется из самого меньшего размера экрана
Я пытаюсь адоптировать свой сайт для мобильных устройств, но у меня возникла проблема в том, что размер текста используется не тот который должен быть при этом размере экрана, а из раздела с наименьшим размером экрана. (Кэш чистил)
Что я сделал не так?
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
       src: url('shool/static/font/pt-astra-sans.ttf') format('truetype');
       
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
   }
   
   
   body{
       background-color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
       color: aliceblue;
       font-size: larger;
   }
       .handler{
       
           background-color: #222222;
           border-radius: 30px;
           padding: 20px 20px;
           margin-top: 50px;
   
       }
   
       h1.text-home-name{
           font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
           font-size: 50px;
           text-align: center;
   
       }
   
       a.button{
           color: rgb(117, 110, 110);
           text-decoration: none;
           margin-top: 20px;
           margin-left: 43%;
           margin-right: 40%;
           background-color: #acacac;
           border: none;
           color: white;
           padding: 10px 10px;
           text-align: center;
           text-decoration: none;
           display: inline-block;
           font-size: 24px;
           border-radius: 15px;
       }
   
       .text-homes{
   
           margin-left: 15%;
           margin-right: 15%;
           padding: 20px 10px;
           font-size: 19px;
           border-radius: 20px;
           font-family: 'MyCustomFont', sans-serif;
       }
   
       div.opensorsu {
   
           margin-top: 5px;
           margin-left: 5%;
           margin-right: 30%;
           border-radius: 20px;
           padding: 20px 20px;
   
       }
   
       h1.opensorsu_text_h1{
           font-size: 25px;
           text-align: center;
       
       }
   
       p.opensorsu_text_p{
           padding-left: 10px;
           margin-bottom: 100px;
           margin-top: 40px;
           font-family: 'MyCustomFont', sans-serif;
   
       }
   
       img.opensorsu_img_github{
           float: left;
           margin-right: 20px;
       }
   
       div.home-all{
           background-color: #1f1e1e;
           border-radius: 30px;
           padding: 20px 20px;
           margin-top: 50px;
           height: 500px;
       }
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
       h1.voprs{
           text-align: center;
       }
   
       h2.tasks{
           text-align: center;
       }
   
       .btn-answer{
           display: flex;
           align-items: center;
           justify-content: center;
           height: 100%;
           flex-wrap: wrap;
   
       }
   
       .btns-answer{
           margin: 5%;
           height: 50px;
           width: 110px;
           border-radius: 10px 20px;
   
       }
   
       button.exit{
           float: right;
           margin-right: 1%;
           background-image: url('exit.png');
           background-size: cover;
           cursor: pointer;
           width: 35px;
           height: 40px;
           background-color: transparent;
           border: none;
       }
   
   
       
   
   
   @media (min-width: 411px) and (max-width: 649px){ 
       .opensorsu{
           font-size: 100px;
       }
       div.opensorsu {
           margin-top: 5px;
           margin-left: 20px;
           margin-right: 20px;
           border-radius: 20px;
           padding: 20px 20px; 
           font-size: 30px;
       }
   
       img.opensorsu_img_github{
           height: 300px;
       }
   }
   
   @media (min-width: 411px){
       .text-homes {
          
           font-size: 1em;
          
       }
   } 

